# Cross Version Compatible Android Tabbed Layout

Tags: android, tabactivity

I'm looking to create a cross-version compatible android tabbed layout.

The problem I'm running into is when implementing Google's example of TabActivity, I get a depreciation notice. The app I'm writing needs to be compatible down to 2.1, and I'm not finding a clear cut way to make it compatible.

I am aware of the versioning by folder (/layout-v4, /layout-v14, etc) but if possible I want to avoid this.

Are fragments the answer here and if so, does the Android Compatibility Layer V4 become the key to solving this problem?

Comment: Deprecation does not mean that it does not work anymore. Fragments with compatibility lib is probably better. Resources by version / etc also

Comment: I am aware, but I'd rather not write code that has been flagged for depreciation. That's common sense.

Comment: Then use Fragments, There is a lot deprecated around `Activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the best approach might be to use the excellent (and free) ActionBarSherlock, so you can add Android 3+ action bar (including tabs) to apps going all the way back to v2.x versions.

I've used it on a few apps and it's pretty easy. I think it's the right approach to use the proper Action Bar interface across platform versions, and they include tabs and replace the whole TabActivity thing, which was pretty horrible anyway.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: When I tried using actionbar sherlock I got hundreds of java errors about cast converting the activities within it. Do you know what I've done wrong there? I know I'm supposed to reference the support package from Google, but I have included that as a library already.

Comment: Depending on what version of ABS you use, you may not need the support library. You need to make sure you use methods like getSupportActionBar() rather than getActionBar